# Protect_from_forgery except for one action in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, csrf

I want to turn off `protect_from_forgery` if `my_controller#my_action` is called using the `.json` format.

Is this possible? Or do you have to choose whether or not to `protect_from_forgery` any entire application? Basically is there `protect_from_forgery, except: [my_controller#my_action.json]`?

Answer (score 0):

Found this [snippet](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c60be72c5243c21303b067c9c5cc398111cf48c8/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb#L88). You can put this same block inside of any controller, and define `json_request to be any helper you want.`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #     protect_from_forgery
  #     skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :json_request?
  #
  #     protected
  #
  #     def json_request?
  #       request.format.json?
  #     end
  #   end
```